# Configure Jenkins EC2-Plugin with Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, amazon-ec2

I am trying to configure the Jenkins EC2-Plugin via Groovy.
Plugin code: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ec2-plugin

I'm trying to setup the cloud with a name to get started

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.plugins.ec2.*
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.*

SlaveTemplate awsTemplate = new SlaveTemplate(
  'ami-1234567',
  '',
  '',
  'sg-1234567',
  't2.micro',
  true,
  'foo',
  '',
  'stuff',
  'run code',
  '/var/tmp',
  'more code',
  '4',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  false,
  'subnet-1234567',
  '',
  '60',
  false,
  '',
  'iam-profile',
  false,
  false,
  '',
  false,
  '',
  true,
  false
)

def slaveTemplates = [awsTemplate]

def ec2Cloud = new AmazonEC2Cloud(
  'foo',
  true,
  '',
  'us-west-2',
  '',
  '10',
  slaveTemplates
)

def cloudList = Jenkins.instance.clouds
cloudList.add(ec2Cloud)
```

Any ideas?

These are the error messages

```
Error: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate
```

or

```
Error: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud
```

Comment: See the Gist list below for the best answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `SlaveTemplate` does not match any of the constructors: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ec2-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/ec2/SlaveTemplate.java

For example, the third parameter (`spotConfig`) is looking for a `SpotConfiguration` object. You currently have an empty string defined there. (You can replace that with `null`.)

Also, the instance-type parameter should be an `InstanceType`, not a string. To correct that, you'll want to add `import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.InstanceType` to the top of the groovy script and replace `'t2.micro'` with `InstanceType.fromValue('t2.micro')`.

For a full example, see https://gist.github.com/vrivellino/97954495938e38421ba4504049fd44ea

Comment: Thank you for this, not sure why it took me so long to find this.

One question before I start playing with this, will running this will overwrite the configuration that's there?

Comment: I don't believe it will - I believe it will add a new cloud configuration.

Comment: I'd like to not create a new cloud, just work within my existing one.

Do you know if it's possible to add a new template at runtime with a groovy script? I tried just doing "cloud.templates.add(new_template)" but got an UnsupportedOperationException on an UnmodifiableCollection. 

I've been digging around the source of the plugin and it don't see and exposed functionality to add/remove/update templates.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I modified an existing cloud configuration and added a new SlaveTemplate:

```
Jenkins.instance.clouds.each {
    if (it.displayName == "SOME_NAME") {
        SlaveTemplate slaveTemplate = new SlaveTemplate(...)
        Field field = hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud.class.getDeclaredField("templates")
        field.setAccessible(true);
        List templates = (List) field.get(it)
        templates.add(slaveTemplate)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion to modify an existing template, but i get an error ```Script1.groovy: 23: unable to resolve class Field 
 @ line 23, column 15.
           Field field = hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud.class.getDeclaredField("templates")```

Answer (score 1):

In your question it appears that you want to configure ec2 instance programmatically in Jenkins using groovy.

> **for example**: in order to run automation tests on my mobile app, I'd like to create ec2 instance which builds the apk/ipa , cloning the project
>   test with appium/selenium framework and running tests on my pull
>   request. the ec2 would be with specific AMI (which contains the
>   environment and several frameworks) from type M-Xlarge.

**Solution**: SlaveTemplate object is the "pojo" object representing the ec2 instance. You can use the code documentation that presents which constructors, properties and public methods you can use, The link is [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ec2-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/ec2/SlaveTemplate.java)

**You can edit  ec2 instance configuration** (using set methods) or **you can create new ec2 instance** (using constructor),I'll attach an example:

In order to edit your instance:

```
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def ec2_instances = instance.clouds[0].getTemplates().each{
  if(it.labels == 'myInstanceLabelNameThatShouldBeChanged'){
    it.setAmi('ami-xxx')
    it.maxTotalUses=3
    it.launchTimeout=60000
  }
}
```

In order to **create instance from scratch**:

Use SlaveTemplate constructor and add it to your clouds array:

```
    public SlaveTemplate(String ami, String zone, SpotConfiguration spotConfig, String securityGroups, String remoteFS,
        InstanceType type, boolean ebsOptimized, String labelString, Node.Mode mode, String description, String initScript,
        String tmpDir, String userData, String numExecutors, String remoteAdmin, AMITypeData amiType, String jvmopts,
        boolean stopOnTerminate, String subnetId, List<EC2Tag> tags, String idleTerminationMinutes, int minimumNumberOfInstances,
        String instanceCapStr, String iamInstanceProfile, boolean deleteRootOnTermination,
        boolean useEphemeralDevices, boolean useDedicatedTenancy, String launchTimeoutStr, boolean associatePublicIp,
        String customDeviceMapping, boolean connectBySSHProcess, boolean monitoring,
        boolean t2Unlimited, ConnectionStrategy connectionStrategy, int maxTotalUses) {
```

An example, Using this wonderful [reference](https://gist.github.com/alisade/0137ac9ce0928827030673a0645ba923):

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.plugins.ec2.*
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.InstanceType

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

def ec2_cloud_name = 'exampleCloud'
def ec2_instance_cap = 5
def worker_description = 'jenkins-worker'
def worker_label_string = 'worker'
def ami_id = 'ami-xxx'
def security_groups = 'sg-123,sg-456'
def subnet_id = 'subnet-someSUbnet'
def instance_type = 'm2.xlarge'
def instance_profile_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::123:instance-profile/JenkinsInstanceProfile'
def number_of_executors = 5

def ec2_tags = [
  new EC2Tag('Name', 'jenkins-worker')
]

def priv_key_txt = ''''''

def worker_ami = new SlaveTemplate(
  // String ami
  ami_id,
  // String zone
  '',
  // SpotConfiguration spotConfig
  null,
  // String securityGroups
  security_groups,
  // String remoteFS
  '',
  // InstanceType type
  InstanceType.fromValue(instance_type),
  // boolean ebsOptimized
  false,
  // String labelString
  worker_label_string,
  // Node.Mode mode
  Node.Mode.NORMAL,
  // String description
  worker_description,
  // String initScript
  '',
  // String tmpDir
  '',
  // String userData
  '',
  // String numExecutors
  "${number_of_executors}",
  // String remoteAdmin
  '',
  // AMITypeData amiType
  new UnixData(null, null),
  // String jvmopts
  '',
  // boolean stopOnTerminate
  false,
  // String subnetId
  subnet_id,
  // List<EC2Tag> tags
  ec2_tags,
  // String idleTerminationMinutes
  '30',
  // boolean usePrivateDnsName
  true,
  // String instanceCapStr
  '50',
  // String iamInstanceProfile
  instance_profile_arn,
  // boolean useEphemeralDevices
  true,
  // boolean useDedicatedTenancy
  false,
  // String launchTimeoutStr
  '1800',
  // boolean associatePublicIp
  false,
  // String customDeviceMapping
  '',
  // boolean connectBySSHProcess
  false,
  // boolean connectUsingPublicIp
  false
)

def new_cloud = new AmazonEC2Cloud(
  // String cloudName
  ec2_cloud_name,
  // boolean useInstanceProfileForCredentials
  true,
  // String credentialsId
  '',
  // String region
  'us-east-1',
  // String privateKey
  priv_key_txt,
  // String instanceCapStr
  "${ec2_instance_cap}",
  // List<? extends SlaveTemplate> templates
  [worker_ami]
)

instance.clouds.add(new_cloud)
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the only constructor available for this class has the following signature:

```
public AmazonEC2Cloud(
  String cloudName, 
  boolean useInstanceProfileForCredentials, 
  String credentialsId, 
  String region, 
  String privateKey, 
  String instanceCapStr, 
  List<? extends SlaveTemplate> templates
)
```

Comment: I'm having problems with cloud class.  Any ideas how to configure that?