# Configure amazon-ecs slave plugin using Groovy on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to configure amazon-ecs-plugin for Jenkins using `init.groovy` script, but couldn't find and docs on it. I'm new to groovy based configuration automation

Tried to get all the properties using

```
import jenkins.model.*
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.*
ECSCloud.metaClass.properties.each {println it.name+":\t"+it.type }
```

The Output:

```
regionName:           class java.lang.String
searchName:           class java.lang.String
slaveTimoutInSeconds: int
searchIndex:          interface hudson.search.SearchIndex
ACL:                  class hudson.security.ACL
descriptor:           class hudson.model.Descriptor
credentialsId:        class java.lang.String
search:               class hudson.search.Search
ecsService:           class com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSService
class:                class java.lang.Class
searchUrl:            class java.lang.String
tunnel:               class java.lang.String
templates:            interface java.util.List
cluster:              class java.lang.String
jenkinsUrl:           class java.lang.String
amazonECSClient:      class com.amazonaws.services.ecs.AmazonECSClient
displayName:          class java.lang.String
```

But, not sure how to proceed with sub-classes like
`ecsService: class com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSService`

not sure, how to define that property

```
def ecs-cloud = new ECSCloud(
  regionName="String"
  ecsService="<NOT SURE HOT TO CONFIGURE THIS>"
......
)
```

The `.xml` file after a manual configuration look like

```
<clouds>
    <com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSCloud plugin="scalable-amazon-ecs@1.0">
      <name>ECS-CLUSTER-NAME</name>
      <templates>
        <com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSTaskTemplate>
          <label>jnlp-slave</label>
          <image>jenkinsci/jnlp-slave</image>
          <remoteFSRoot>/home/jenkins</remoteFSRoot>
          <memory>800</memory>
          <cpu>800</cpu>
          <privileged>false</privileged>
          <taskDefinitionArn>TASK-DEF-ARN</taskDefinitionArn>
        </com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSTaskTemplate>
      </templates>
      <credentialsId></credentialsId>
      <cluster>arn:aws:ecs:REGION:ACCOUNTID:cluster/ECS-CLUSTER-NAME</cluster>
      <regionName>REGION</regionName>
      <tunnel></tunnel>
      <jenkinsUrl>JENKINS-URL</jenkinsUrl>
      <slaveTimoutInSeconds>900</slaveTimoutInSeconds>
      <ecsService>
        <credentialsId></credentialsId>
        <regionName>REGION</regionName>
      </ecsService>
    </com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSCloud>
  </clouds>
```

Thanks in advance.

### Update

[Configure Jenkins EC2-Plugin with Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605219/configure-jenkins-ec2-plugin-with-groovy)
Similar question for using EC2 Plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I made some headway on this. It's not idempotent, but it works. The code was tailored for my use case, but shouldn't be too hard for you to tweak for your own.

```
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.logging.Logger
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ecs-cluster")

logger.info("Loading Jenkins")
import jenkins.model.*
instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSTaskTemplate.MountPointEntry
def mounts = Arrays.asList(
  new MountPointEntry(
    name="docker",
    sourcePath="/var/run/docker.sock",
    containerPath="/var/run/docker.sock",
    readOnly=false),
  new MountPointEntry(
    name="jenkins",
    sourcePath="/home/jenkins",
    containerPath="/home/jenkins",
    readOnly=false),
)

logger.info("Creating template")
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSTaskTemplate
def ecsTemplate = new ECSTaskTemplate(
  templateName="jnlp-slave-with-docker",
  label="ecs-with-docker",
  image="jnlp-slave-with-docker:latest",
  remoteFSRoot=null,
  memory=2048,
  cpu=512,
  privileged=false,
  logDriverOptions=null,
  environments=null,
  extraHosts=null,
  mountPoints=mounts
)

logger.info("Retrieving ecs cloud config by descriptor")
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSCloud
ecsCloud = new ECSCloud(
  name="name",
  templates=Arrays.asList(ecsTemplate),
  credentialsId=null,
  cluster="arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456789:cluster/ecs-jenkins-slave",
  regionName="us-east-1",
  jenkinsUrl="https://my-jenkins.com",
  slaveTimoutInSeconds=60
)

logger.info("Gettings clouds")
def clouds = instance.clouds
clouds.add(ecsCloud)
logger.info("Saving jenkins")
instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The ECSTaskTemplate in the above answer no longer works. memoryReservation is missing.

Here is a working example for `ECSTaskTemplate`

```
def ecsTemplate = new ECSTaskTemplate(
  templateName="jnlp-slave",
  label="ecs",
  image="jenkinsci/jnlp-slave",
  remoteFSRoot=null,
  memory=0,
  memoryReservation=2048,
  cpu=512,
  privileged=false,
  logDriverOptions=null,
  environments=null,
  extraHosts=null,
  mountPoints=null
)
```