# Jenkins ECSCloud

Tags: jenkins, groovy, amazon-ecs

I have been following the below answer to add ECS Clouds to Jenkins for slaves

[Configure amazon-ecs slave plugin using Groovy on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059428/configure-amazon-ecs-slave-plugin-using-groovy-on-jenkins)

The Plugin has since been modifed and I've found the following JavaDocs

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/amazon-ecs/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/amazonecs/ECSCloud.html

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/amazon-ecs/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/amazonecs/ECSTaskTemplate.html

I've been able to modify the ECSTaskTemplate to add the newer variables but I keep getting an error on the ECSCloud

```
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.logging.Logger
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ecs-cluster")

logger.info("Loading Jenkins")
import jenkins.model.*
instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSTaskTemplate.MountPointEntry
def mounts = Arrays.asList(
  new MountPointEntry(
    name="docker",
    sourcePath="/var/run/docker.sock",
    containerPath="/var/run/docker.sock",
    readOnly=false),
  new MountPointEntry(
    name="jenkins",
    sourcePath="/home/jenkins",
    containerPath="/home/jenkins",
    readOnly=false),
)

logger.info("Creating template")
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSTaskTemplate
def ecsTemplate = new ECSTaskTemplate(
  templateName="jnlp-slave-with-docker",
  label="ecs-with-docker",
  taskDefinitionOverride='',
  image="jnlp-slave-with-docker:latest",
  repositoryCredentials=null,
  launchType="EC2",
  networkMode="default",  
  remoteFSRoot=null,
  memory=2048,
  memoryReservation=2048,
  cpu=512,
  subnets=null,
  securityGroups=null,
  assignPublicIp=false,
  privileged=false,
  containerUser=null,
  logDriverOptions=null,
  environments=null,
  extraHosts=null,
  mountPoints=mounts,
  portMappings=null
)

logger.info("Retrieving ecs cloud config by descriptor")
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSCloud
ecsCloud = new ECSCloud(
  name="name",
  templates=Arrays.asList(ecsTemplate),
  credentialsId=null,
  cluster="arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456789:cluster/ecs-jenkins-slave",
  regionName="us-east-1",
  jenkinsUrl="https://my-jenkins.com",
  slaveTimoutInSeconds=60,
  retentionTimeout=5
)

logger.info("Gettings clouds")
def clouds = instance.clouds
clouds.add(ecsCloud)
logger.info("Saving jenkins")
instance.save()
```

Error is as below

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSCloud(java.lang.String, java.util.Arrays$ArrayList, null, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be resolved by useing ECSCloud setters as below

```
ecsCloud = new ECSCloud(
  name="name",
  credentialsId=null,
  cluster="arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456789:cluster/ecs-jenkins-slave"
)

ecsCloud.setTemplates(dockerTemplates)
ecsCloud.setRegionName("us-east-1")
ecsCloud.setJenkinsUrl("https://my-jenkins.com")
ecsCloud.setSlaveTimeoutInSeconds(60)
```